# Are file scoped atomics subject to the initialization order fiasco?

Tags: c++, c++11, static, initialization, undefined-behavior

Consider the following, where we have two file scoped objects in different translation units, which is the usual setup for undefined-behavior by way of the initialization order fiasco:

**a.hpp**:

```
struct thing {
public:
    thing(int value);
    ~thing();

    int value() const;

    static int count();

private:
    int _value;
};
```

**a.cpp**:

```
#include "a.hpp"

#include <atomic>

namespace {
    std::atomic<int> things;
}

thing::thing(int value) : _value(value) {
    ++things;
}

thing::~thing() {
    --things;
}

int thing::value() const {
    return _value;
}

int thing::count() {
    return things.load();
}
```

**b.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "a.hpp"

namespace {
    thing static_thing(42);
}

void foo() {
    std::cout << static_thing.value() << ' ' << thing::count() << '\n';
}
```

Is this code subject to an initialization order fiasco between the file scoped atomic `things` in **a.cpp** and the file scoped `static_thing` in **b.cpp**? If not, why not? In particular, what is special about std::atomic that removes what would otherwise be a clear init order fiasco? Is there a particular concept that can be named to enforce this with a static assert? Something like:

```
static_assert(std::is_trivial<decltype(things)>::value, "file static counter is not trivial");
```

If not `std::is_trivial`, is there another concept and associated type trait that better models this?

Conversely, is there a de-initialization fiasco? Same questions about if so, why, or why not.

Comment: My brief research in the matter suggest that given the guarantee that `std::atomic<int>` must be specialized, and specialized atomics have certain properties, `std::atomic<int>` would just like a POD, for initialization order, e.g. no fiasco. However, this case can also be solved just like most other cases subject to init fiasco: but declaring the static objects in function static scope, and taking advantage of the fact that function static-scoped objects must be init-ed before the first entry into the function.

Comment: The order of construction of static objects in different translation is still unspecified.   Use of `std::atomic` does not change that.   Why would you expect it to?   Particular compilers may instantiate atomics first, but that is not required.

Comment: @Peter because std::atomic<int> has a constexpr constructor and is being initialized with a constant, and has a trivial destructor. This suggests that the object is effectively immortal. Since static init takes place before any dynamic init, and since there is nothing to be done to destroy it, it is basically immortal. I don't see how there can be an initialization order fiasco w.r.t. anything with dynamic initialization.

Comment: The fiasco occurs when creating objects - subsequently living forever (with end of time being program termination) is irrelevant. Constant initialisation (including `constexpr`) precedes dynamic initialisation and comes after zero initialisation according to C++14 3.6.2/2, but the issue is reliance on an unspecified initialisation order of ANY two static objects.  When there are two static objects with `constexpr` constructor accepting a pointer, both pointers must be initialised first, and that requires construction of the pointees.  If there is reliance on their order of construction .....

Answer (score 3):

`std::atomic<>` is a standard layout type with trivial default constructors, and trivial destructors. Therefore, it is initialized at *static initialization* phase, before the *dynamic initialization* phase when constructors of global objects get called.

In other words, no initialization order fiasco happens here.

Since you do not explicitly initialize the namespace scoped `std::atomic<int>`, it is going to be zero-initialized.

> § 3.6.2 Initialization of non-local variables
>
> Variables with static storage duration (3.7.1) or thread storage duration (3.7.2) shall be zero-initialized (8.5) before any other initialization takes place.
>
> Together, zero-initialization and constant initialization are called static initialization; all other initialization is dynamic initialization. Static initialization shall be performed before any dynamic initialization takes place.

Comment: This is correct modulo compiler bugs (See [this one](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/76198/vs-2017-compiler-creates-broken-debug-build-using.html) which affects VS 2017 15.3)

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of the C++ "initialisation order fiasco" is that it only applies when constructors need to be called at runtime. If the code can devolve down into the initialisation of a memory location to a fixed value, then that value gets put in the "initialised data" linker section (`.data`) like every other pre-initialised POD (Plain Ol' Data), and there is no fiasco.

I'd suggest that an `atomic` meets that very criterion.